# Referring to parts of a list for a calculation (Python)

Tags: python

I have to calculate the distance between a set of points that are given and multiple points which come from a list.

an example of a line from the list is;

```
['14', '"Name of place"', '-31.000', '115.000']
```

As the calc distance function takes four parameters I  put the two given points in then then long and lat values of the list.

My understanding was to do this I could simply refer to the list aka 'List' then which part of each line I want to access aka 2 and 3

```
        User_E = raw_input("First enter your longitude(easting) value")
        User_N = raw_input("Now enter your latitude(northing) value")
        Radius = raw_input("Now enter a search radius in kilometres")
        for lines in ListOfLandmarks:
            CalculateDistance( User_N, User_E, ListOfLandmarks[2], ListOfLandmarks[3] )
```

when I run the program I receive the below error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'list'
```

Iv'e tried to use `int` and `float` to identify them as numbers but they produce the following:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

def CalculateDistance( latOne, lonOne, latTwo, lonTwo ):
DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
alpha = 90 - latTwo
beta  = 90 - latOne

cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
Distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
return Distance
```

Just wondering where I am going wrong, cheers!

Comment: `Listname[2]` and 3 is a string, so wrap them in `float()` when you call the function... What are `givena` and `givenb`? We need a bit more of your actual code to see what is going on.

Comment: Iv'e tried 


CalculateDistance( float(givena), float(givenb), float(ListName[2]), float(ListName[3]) )

which gets

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number



sorry, given a and b are user input coordinates

Comment: Why have you got both single and double quotes for your string?  Are you going to be printing that with the double quotes, or is there some other reason for doing so?

Comment: Edit your answer to show how `givena` and `givenb` are defined, and what `ListName` is. I am guessing that `float(ListName[2]` is working fine, but the others are not. If it thinks they are a list, you might have to add a `[0]` at the end, but without more code, we can't tell. Don't be shy. You can put a lot of text into your question. Just format it by selecting and clicking on the {} to make it show up as code.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code example? Specifically what ListName contains (is it a list, or a list of lists?) and the function CalculateDistance.

Comment: ListOfLandmarks is from a file that is read into a list earlier on, it contains multiple lines like the example one so list of lists, should have specified that originally, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping the conversion issues (as you store your coordinates as strings instead of floats)

```
for lines in ListOfLandmarks:
        CalculateDistance( User_N, User_E, ListOfLandmarks[2], ListOfLandmarks[3] )
```

should be

```
for lines in ListOfLandmarks:
        CalculateDistance( User_N, User_E, lines[2], lines[3] )
```

As you ask for distance to the particular landmark that you iterate through, `ListOfLandmarks[2]` is a **second landmark** (so a `list` which your interpreter does not know how to compare/use in the `float` context), while the **first coordinate** of the current landmark is `lines[2]`